# Java directory error for finding text in file

Tags: java, file, file-io

Trying to develop a program that will search through the given path to find the file (if user gives a name or just search through them all) and then look for the ext, content and last date modified. I can't get the content part to work correctly (So when I enter dog, I was all the files that contain that inside of them)& I haven't started working on the last date modified. I've been trying to do contains.name but it's not working properly. Thanks for any help!

Right now I'm getting this error with how my code is now.

```
Main.java:31: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
               return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(fileN.toLowerCase()) && name.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext.toLowerCase()) && find(name, content);
                                                                                                                                        ^
1 error
```

When I don't throw my find method I get this output:

```
Search by path, name, extension, content and date.


Enter starting directory for the search (like c:\temp): /Users/KaylaSiemon/Documents
Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all): 
Enter the file extension (like txt or enter for all): docx
Enter content to search for (like cscd211 or enter for any): kayla
Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2013 or enter for any): kj

java.io.FileNotFoundException: COVER LETTER.docx (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Main.find(Main.java:53)
    at Main$1.accept(Main.java:31)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Program Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Search by path, name, extension, content and date.\n\n");

      System.out.print("Enter starting directory for the search (like c:" + "\\" + "temp): ");
      String direct = kb.nextLine();
      File dir = new File(direct);

      System.out.print("Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all): ");
      final String fileN = kb.nextLine();

      System.out.print("Enter the file extension (like txt or enter for all): ");
      final String ext = kb.next();

      System.out.print("Enter content to search for (like cscd211 or enter for any): ");
      final String content = kb.next();

      System.out.print("Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2013 or enter for any): ");
      String date = kb.next();
      System.out.println();
      FilenameFilter filter = 
         new FilenameFilter() {         
            public boolean accept
            (File dir, String name) {
               Scanner input = new Scanner(name);

               return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(fileN.toLowerCase()) && name.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext.toLowerCase()) && find(name, content);
            }
         };
      String[] children = dir.list(filter);
      if (children == null) {
         System.out.println("Either dir does not exist or is not a directory");
      } 
      else {
         for (int i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
            String filename = children[i];
            System.out.println(dir + "/" +filename);
         }
      }
   }

   public static boolean find(String f, String searchString) throws IOException
   {
      boolean result = false;
      Scanner in = null;

      try
      {
         in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));

         while(in.hasNextLine() && !result)         {
            result = in.nextLine().indexOf(searchString) >= 0;
         }
      }

      catch(IOException e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      finally
      {
         try
         { 
            in.close(); 
         } 
         catch(Exception e)         { 
         /*ignore*/
         }
      }
      return result;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the entirety of your file IO code in the following block:

```
try{
    //your code here
}catch(IOException e){
    //code to handle exception if there is a problem with the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Main.java:31: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
               return name.toLowerCase().startsWith(fileN.toLowerCase()) && name.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext.toLowerCase()) && find(name, content);
                                                                                                                                        ^
1 error
```

Is telling you that a method you are calling is throwing, in this case, an `IOException` but the exception is untreated.  Neither is it caught nor is it re-thrown.

You could wrap the statement in a `try-catch` clause at this point, as you won't be able to re-throw it, but a little more investigation might provide a better alternative...

The `find` method doesn't actually need to thrown an `IOException` as you've already dealt with it...how ever, I would argue that this is a bad idea, as the caller should be dealing with the exception...catch 22...

So instead, your `FilenameFilter` could look more like...

```
FilenameFilter filter
                = new FilenameFilter() {
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        Scanner input = new Scanner(name);

                        boolean accept = false;

                        try {
                            accept = name.toLowerCase().startsWith(fileN.toLowerCase()) && name.toLowerCase().endsWith("." + ext.toLowerCase()) && find(name, content);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return accept;
                    }
                };
```

And your `find` method more like...

```
public static boolean find(String f, String searchString) throws IOException {
    boolean result = false;
    Scanner in = null;

    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));

        while (in.hasNextLine() && !result) {
            result = in.nextLine().indexOf(searchString) >= 0;
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*ignore*/
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now...

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: COVER LETTER.docx (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Main.find(Main.java:53)
    at Main$1.accept(Main.java:31)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:1155)
    at Main.main(Main.java:34)
```

Is a result of a number things...

First, your `FilenameFilter` passes two things, the `dir` as a `File` and the `name` of the file as a `String`.  The `name` contains only the name of the file, it does not contain the directory the file resides in, that's the purpose of the `dir` parameter...

Second, you specify some arbitrary path, in this case `/Users/KaylaSiemon/Documents`

Third, the location the program is run in is not likely to the same as the path you are trying to search...

All this means is, when you try and do `in = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));`, Java is actually looking in the current directory for the file, not the directory you had previously specified.

That is, instead of looking for `/Users/KaylaSiemon/Documents/COVER LETTER.docx` it's actually looking for `./COVER LETTER.docx`

The simplest fix would be to change the parameters of the `find` method to use a `File` reference instead of a `String`, `File` provides better resolution of path contexts then a `String` could...

For example...

```
public static boolean find(File f, String searchString) throws IOException {
```

This means when you call it, you will need to pass it a `File` reference, for example

```
find(new File(dir, name), content)
```